# Div is not displaying properly

Tags: php, padding

I am crating a registration form. When the user clicks the register button, if there is any errors I need to show them.For that I wrote the following code,

```
<?php  if($flag==0)
       {
   ?>
         <div class="info-message">
                <?php echo $error_message;?>
         </div><?php 
      }
```

the css is,

```
    .info-message{
     background:yellow;
     padding:10px;
     border:1px solid black;
     color:black;
     width:780px;
}
```

but if the value of `$flag = 1`, padding space of the div is visible, but I needn't show the div if the value of `$flag != 0`. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: This is the part of the code. We don't know if the `$flag` isn't changed somewhere. Put more code please.

Comment: try using `var_dump($flag);` before the `if` statement and see its value

Comment: Please show us the code which sets the $flag variable

Comment: understand the mistake,$flag was not initialized.thank u Smith and thank u Ejay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div.info-message` will only appear if `$flag == 0`. If you don´t want to show an empty div with padding you have to check also `if $error_message == false`! If that is not helpful I don´t understand your question!